# foreach on multiple fileupload doesn't stop on error

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

i'm a very big newbie @ php. Hope you are considerate :)

i have this script and a litte problem. I want to check in the first foreach part if the select files are images. If the files are images and not to large it should give an ok for upload!

but it's important to check first all images!

**the problem i have is for example:**

in inputfield 1 i put an image with 1mb

in inputfield 2 i put an textfile

when i press submit the first image from the input is moving into the folder and than stopping on the textfile with an error **<- no php ERROR just my own error (no image file or image is too big)**

edit: it seems that the `if ($upload_ok == true)` part doesn't work

first i want that all input fields getting checked (validextension,fileextension,size)  and when all inputfields ok the images can move to the folder ( starting with `if ($upload_ok == true)` ).

```
if (!empty($_FILES))
    {
    $upload_ok=array();

    foreach($_FILES as $key => $file)
            {
            $validExtensions = array('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.png');
            $fileExtension = strtolower(strrchr($file['name'], "."));

            if ((in_array($fileExtension, $validExtensions) && ($file['error'] == 0))||$file['error'] == 4)
                    {
                    $upload_ok=true;
                    echo('true');
                    }
            else
                    {
                    $upload_ok=false;
                    $result=false;
                    echo('false');
                    }
            }
    // if(!in_array(false ,$upload_ok))
    if ($upload_ok == true)
            {
            foreach($_FILES as $key => $file)
                    {
                    if ($file['error'] == 0)
                            {
                            $newNamePrefix = $picName . '_';
                            $CounterPrefix = sprintf("%02d",(preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","", $key)));
                            $fileExtension = strtolower(strrchr($file['name'], "."));
                            $manipulator = new ImageManipulator($file['tmp_name']);
                            $newImage = $manipulator->resample(1024, 1024);
                            $manipulator->save($imgRoot . $maschineFolder . $picFolder . $newNamePrefix . $CounterPrefix . $fileExtension);
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
```

i made a small pastebin with the hole script [here](http://pastebin.com/4mLgyuXc)

Comment: Could you please add to paragraphs to your question: 1. What's the desired outcome? 2. What goes wrong?

Comment: it is no php error if you mean that! i edited the question for better understanding.. i hope :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand you correctly...

**select this**

```
$upload_ok=array();

foreach($_FILES as $key => $file)
        {
        $validExtensions = array('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.png');
        $fileExtension = strtolower(strrchr($file['name'], "."));

        if ((in_array($fileExtension, $validExtensions) && ($file['error'] == 0))||$file['error'] == 4)
                {
                $upload_ok=true;
                echo('true');
                }
        else
                {
                $upload_ok=false;
                $result=false;
                echo('false');
                }
        }
// if(!in_array(false ,$upload_ok))
```

**and replace it with**

```
$error = false;
$validExtensions = array('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.png');

foreach(array_keys($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']) as $key){
    if($_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'][$key] == 4) continue;
    $fileExtension = strtolower(strrchr($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'][$key], "."));
    $error |= ! in_array($fileExtension, $validExtensions);
    $error |= ! $_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'][$key] == 0;
    if($error){
        $result=false;
        break;
    }
}
```

**also find this code:**

```
// if(!in_array(false ,$upload_ok))
if ($upload_ok == true)
        {
        foreach($_FILES as $key => $file)
                {
                if ($file['error'] == 0)
                        {
                        $newNamePrefix = $picName . '_';
                        $CounterPrefix = sprintf("%02d",(preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","", $key)));
                        $fileExtension = strtolower(strrchr($file['name'], "."));
                        $manipulator = new ImageManipulator($file['tmp_name']);
                        $newImage = $manipulator->resample(1024, 1024);
                        $manipulator->save($imgRoot . $maschineFolder . $picFolder . $newNamePrefix . $CounterPrefix . $fileExtension);
                        }
                }
        }
```

**and replace it with:**

```
if ($error === 0){
    foreach(array_keys($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']) as $key){
        if ($_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'][$key] == 0){
            $newNamePrefix = $picName . '_';
            $CounterPrefix = sprintf("%02d",(preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","", $key)));
            $fileExtension = strtolower(strrchr($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'][$key], "."));
            $manipulator = new ImageManipulator($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'][$key]);
            $newImage = $manipulator->resample(1024, 1024);
            $manipulator->save($imgRoot . $maschineFolder . $picFolder . $newNamePrefix . $CounterPrefix . $fileExtension);
        }
    }
}
```

**and change your inputs from**

```
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload1" id="fileToUpload1" accept="image/*" />
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload2" id="fileToUpload2" accept="image/*" />
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload3" id="fileToUpload2" accept="image/*" />
```

**to this**

```
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload[]" accept="image/*" />
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload[]" accept="image/*" />
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload[]" accept="image/*" />
```

**or this when you need the reference to the image**

```
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload[1]" accept="image/*" />
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload[2]" accept="image/*" />
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload[3]" accept="image/*" />
```

Answer (score 1):

When checking images, it's best not to rely on the extension. You can do the following to verify the image type:

```
$info   = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$mime   = $info['mime'];
```

`$mime` should now contain a string such as "image/jpeg".  Here's a link to a list of the [mime type values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.image-type-to-mime-type.php).

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use break; and continue; to navigate loops. Not sure what's your desired outcome though.